# ¿Cómo se analizaría sintacticamente "Universidad Politécnica"?

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

Tengo esta oración para analizar:

> Me recomendaron que estudiara **en la Universidad Politécnica**.

La parte en negrita imagino que es un sintagma preposicional que actúa como complemento circunstancial de lugar, "Universidad" sería núcleo de un sintagma nominal... ¿y "Politécnica"? No estoy muy segura, ¿podría ser un sintagma nominal que actúa como complemento del nombre?

Comment: Hola, estudiante. Si buscas en el diccionario la palabra "[politécnico](http://dle.rae.es/politécnico)" verás que se trata de un adjetivo, que en este caso afecta al sustantivo "universidad". Te recomendamos la consulta de este diccionario para resolver estas cuestiones sencillas. ¡Bienvenida al sitio!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero al ser el nombre de la universidad, ¿no sería un sustantivo?

Comment: Okey, ya he encontrado la solución, es un sustantivo que actúa como aposición. Muchas gracias y espero que a alguien le sirva :)

Comment: @Student Para ser aposición, "politécnica" tendría que ser sustantivo y estar entre comas. Es un adjetivo que modifica al sustantivo "universidad", como te dijo Charlie. Por lo tanto, la solución que has encontrado está equivocada y tu comentario induce a error.

Comment: "Politécnica" es un nombre propio (el nombre de una universidad, como puede ser la Complutense o Cambridge) y por lo tanto es un sustantivo, no un adjetivo. Sería como "Me recomendó ir a estudiar a Harvards". Harvards es el nombre de la universidad, por lo que no es un adjetivo. De todas formas, puede que me este equivocando. Muchas gracias por la ayuda! :)

Comment: Saludos @Student. Puedes verlo mejor con el caso del MIT o el Caltech. Si te recomiendan ir al *Instituto Tecnológico de California*, el término *Tecnológico* sigue siendo un adjetivo que modifica al instituto.

Answer (score 3):

En este caso, tenemos dos palabras: «Universidad», que es un sustantivo, y «politécnico», que es un adjetivo cuyo significado, según nos informa la RAE, es «Que abarca muchas ciencias o artes». Es un sintagma nominal, el cual se compone de un nucleo de sustantivo y de otros elementos modificadores, de los que solamente está presente el adjetivo en función de adyacente. Así de simple.

Creo que es posible que la confusión surja de que la palabra politécnica frecuentemente pasa a desempeñar el papel del sustantivo, justo como lo hace "complutense".  Es decir, tiene que ver con el hecho de que la gente diga "Estudio en la Complutense" o cosas así. A modo de ejemplo, tenemos [esto:](https://gacetinmadrid.com/2020/03/09/dos-positivos-por-coronavirus-en-la-complutense-y-la-politecnica-podria-ocasionar-su-cierre-temporal/)

> Dos positivos por coronavirus en la Complutense y la Politécnica podría ocasionar su cierre temporal.

Bien, en este contexto se trata de un nombre propio, y como has reconocido, por lo tanto este nombre *como conjunto* es un sustantivo. No sería de extrañar que nos preguntáramos cómo es posible que sea un sustantivo aquí, pero a la vez un adjetivo en la frase nominal de la pregunta. Lo importante es notar que la categoría morfosintáctica de las palabras «complutense» y «politécnica» ha cambiado al añadirles la palabra «la», o al eliminar el sustantivo «universidad». Es que tanto los adjetivos como los verbos pueden convertirse en sustantivos cuando van acompañados de los artículos.

Por ejemplo, cuando uno se refiere al Cid Campeador, la segunda palabra es un adjetivo que quiere decir (según la RAE):

> Dicho de un guerrero: Que sobresale en el campo de batalla con acciones señaladas.

Sin embargo, a veces simplemente decimos «El Campeador». En vista de eso, a pesar de que este nombre seguramente tiene el papel gramatical de un sustantivo, en general «campeador» sigue siendo un adjetivo. Por eso muchos gramáticos y muchas gramáticas hablan del carácter sustantivador del artículo.  Dice Tomás Jiménez Juliá [sobre el asunto:](https://books.google.com/books?id=0eb8sShGjMgC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=art%C3%ADculo+y+adjetivo+categor%C3%ADa+morfosintactica&source=bl&ots=b8UrIqTwl-&sig=ACfU3U1NujMtUr6mrVbNQj74t1Sj5hNjGg&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwistMjU_pvpAhVGI6wKHarnD60Q6AEwDHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=art%C3%ADculo%20y%20adjetivo%20categor%C3%ADa%20morfosintactica&f=false)

> El carácter sustantivador del artículo es probablemente una de las cuestiones que menos controversia suscita, pese a la existencia de críticas al tipo de ‘transposición sustantiva’ de Alarcos y seguidores.

O sea que el artículo convierte un adjetivo (campeador, complutense, politécnica) en sustantivo por su mera presencia.

---

Con respecto a la idea de que los nombres propios no pueden contener los adjetivos, difiero. Los adjetivos se usan en los nombres propios más a menudo de lo que parece. Por ejemplo, existen nombres tales como Guinea Ecuatorial, Río Grande, y Dios Todopoderoso. Nadie piensa que «grande» no sea un adjetivo, ¿no? «El río es grande». «El dios es todopoderoso». «El país es ecuatorial».

Comment: Fantásticamente explicado. Como nota, el propio diccionario hace aclaraciones como por ejemplo la que aparece en la entrada _[azul](https://dle.rae.es/azul)_, que es un adjetivo pero en la primera acepción podemos ver la marca "U. t. c. s. m.": Usado también como sustantivo masculino. Todo depende de si va acompañando a un sustantivo, o va directamente acompañado por el artículo.